# Convertir fila en columnas mySQL

Tags: mysql

Logro obtener los datos de mi tabla en una fila, lo que deseo es obtener en una columna todos los datos.

TABLA: wpuk_usermete

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El resultado es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Deseo obtener como resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me pueden ayudar porfavor.

Comment: Lo siento, es la primera vez que publico. U_U

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para eso puedes usar GROUP_CONCAT().

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(meta_value SEPARATOR ' ' ) FROM wpuk_usermete
WHERE meta_key IN ('TeamName','TAG','Player01','Player02','Player03','Player04')
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY user_id ASC
```

El resultado de esa select es :

```
PERICOS PR ocalox donortis juansixls cosrld
MANICOS MN osdfc doncsss xssds ccodfd
JOLETONES JLS capitanes rocoles xiiksx kxkkps
```

[Documentacion de GROUP_CONCAT()](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php)

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por responder.

Tengo una duda. Sobre la tabla también tengo: 
```
user_id | meta_key | meta_value
```
y
```
1 | account_status | approved
```
y
```
2 | account_status | noapproved
```
Sobre los re sultados:
``` 
PERICOS PR ocalox donortis juansixls cosrld
MANICOS MN osdfc doncsss xssds ccodfd
JOLETONES JLS capitanes rocoles xiiksx kxkkps
```

Cuando está en "noapproved". No debería salir los datos del user_is = 2
Cuando está en "approved, Sí.

Me puedes ayudar con esto también?

Gracias.

Comment: Si la respuesta te ha ayudado, considera darle a aceptar como válida. En cuanto a la otra pregunta no me queda claro lo que quieres hacer, pero sino tiene nada que ver con esta pregunta que has hecho las normas indican que debes abrir otra pregunta nueva explicando bien ese nuevo problema.

Comment: Ok. Abriré otra pregunta. Gracias